# Dual Boot Windows Server 2012 & Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, server, system-installation, windows, ssd

I have a Dell Poweredge T330 with Windows Server 2012 installed. I want to install UBUNTU 22.04.1 LTS using another new SDD. Is it possible? If yes then can anyone suggest me about it?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with the old procedure for BIOS machines. What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: My system has already an OS installed with RAID 1. Now I want to install another OS (Ubuntu) using a new SSD.  Can you help?

Comment: Again, what exactly do you need to know? All of what you want, especially now that you specified an independent drive - it's harder to install in an array, even worse in something managed by Windows - is as trivial as it can be.

Comment: Bro, I want to dual boot my Windows Server 2012 R2. (A server already running there) I prefer dual boot because I Don't want to lost my access to the existing server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)